# (Bluehost) navigating to the dashboard via mydomain.com/wp-admin/ results in directory listing

Tags: navigation, htaccess, dashboard

I recently had my WordPress blog's domain reassigned as the primary domain on my BlueHost account. The blog is in a sub-folder of `public_html/`. Below is the contents of the `.htaccess` file I re-uploaded to replace the default `.htaccess` file. When I tried navigating to my dashboard by clicking on the Dashboard link from the site, I am greeted with a directory listing for `wp-admin`. However, when I use `ofthreadsandthings.net/wp-admin/index.php`, things are fine.

### The `.htaccess` (root level)

```
# Use PHP54 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php

AddType audio/mp4 .m4a

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?ofthreadsandthings.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ofthreadsandthings/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ofthreadsandthings/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?ofthreadsandthings.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ ofthreadsandthings/index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this directive at the beginning of the .htaccess file should do the trick:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

If this doesn't do the trick, try creating an .htaccess file in the wp-admin folder and place this directive in there (depending on what HTTP server your system runs on and a variety of other settings, modifying just the .htaccess in the root domain might not inherit the directives to subfolders).